# Get values out of a session and save it to database ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oop, session

I'm creating some sort of survey in ASP.NET MVC and when a user fills a create form view all the values are stored in an object that will be saved in a session. 
At the end of the survey I want to save all the objects to the database in one action.

```
Email mails = new Email();
mails = Session["Emails"];

db.Emails.Add(mails);
```

It says:

> cannot implicitly convert type Object to Namespace.models.emails.

The error occurs at this line :

```
mails = Session["Emails"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seesions in ASP.Net, by default, returns the `Object` type. You have to typecast it while assigning.

Try this:

```
if (Session["Emails"] != null) 
{       
   Email mails = (Email)Session["Emails"];  //Assuming Session will contain one email
   db.Emails.Add(mails);
}
```

Comment: but you don't need the `= new Email()` as that object will be abandoned and replaced in the next line.

Comment: @HansKesting: I just copied the OP's code. But you are right, I will update the code.

Comment: Thanks @Saket, i can save the object now, the only problem is that it creates 4 records for some reason? `                    Email mails = (Email)Session["Emails"];
                    Telefoon telefoon = (Telefoon)Session["Telefoon"];
                    Adres adres = (Adres)Session["Adres"];
                    db.Emails.Add(mails);
                    db.Telefoons.Add(telefoon);
                    db.Adres.Add(adres);
                    db.Vaardigheden.Add(vaardigheden);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index","Vrijwilligers");`